# How to decide to leave money invested in Brazil or transfer immediately to my home country?

Tags: investing, currency, international-transfer, germany, brazil

I have sold a property in Brazil this year with the purpose to buy a house in my home country (Germany). However, until I got all the documents ready to transfer the money to germany, I have lost already more than a half of the value of the money, due to the low Brazilian reais in comparison with the euros. Right now, the money that I will get in Germany is much much less than what I needed to buy a house, therefore a house here is no longer an option, at least for now.

since the money is currently "invested in a Brazilian Saving account" with the interest rate of a bit more than 1% per month.

My question is: shall I transfer the money as soon as possible to Germany before the Brazilian reais get worse, and invest in Germany in funds or maybe buy stocks, or shall I leave the money in Brazil and wait to see if the currency will get a bit better so I don't lose so much money with the currency exchange ?

Thanks a lot,
Lia

Comment: Similar situation here. Have been in Brazil for a few years and cumulated a considerable amount of savings. Considering moving back to Canada, but, as the original pôster mentionned, buy the time all mechanisms were in place to move money, the Real started its fall. At 1 day from the Feds decision deadline, I'm getting to the point of forgetting about my money for a few years... In that case, not only will it be at risk of further devaluation, but who knows what other plan this joke of a government has up its sleeve that could futher eat into my hard earned cash (new taxes on Financial transac

Answer (score 2):

If your country of residence is going to be Germany, it is advisable to move money to Germany at the earliest opportunity.

It is hard to predict what will happen in future, i.e. whether Reais will rise or fall compared to Euro.

The question of whether to leave the funds in Brazil or not, should be looked at:

> If you had money in Euro, would you have moved it to Brazil or kept it in Germany?